# encode all columns of a dataframe to UTF-8 in R after pulling from mysql for C50 algorithm

Tags: r, rmysql

I am facing a weird problem, I hope it is related to utf-8 correct me if i am wrong.

I am pulling data from mysql as below

```
library(C50)
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
fetchRecordsQuery<-"SELECT PRODUCT_CODE as PRODUCT_CODE,SUPPLIER_NAME as SUPPLIER_NAME,taxonomy_level1_name as taxonomy_level1_name,taxonomy_level2_name as taxonomy_level2_name,taxonomy_level3_name as taxonomy_level3_name FROM  EVPI_SanityRulesPredict_111.Invoice_111_orig WHERE is_classified=1 LIMIT 30000 OFFSET 0"
connection <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user=userName, password=userPassword, dbname=databaseName, host=hostName, port=as.integer(port))setNamesQuery<-"SET NAMES utf8"
setNamesQuery<-"SET NAMES utf8"
rs <- dbSendQuery(connection, setNamesQuery)
rs <- dbSendQuery(connection, fetchRecordsQuery)
c50data <- fetch(rs, n=-1)
```

This is how i am fetching the data.

When I am printing the data in the console, I can see the Japanese characters as well. After that, I am feeding this data to C50 algorithm as below.

```
ruleModel <- C5.0(as.formula(frmla), data=c50data, rules=TRUE)
```

and the same algorithm is working in windows and it is failing in linux!!

```
*** line 1 of `undefined.data': bad value of `▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒' for attribute `SUPPLIER_NAME'
*** line 2 of `undefined.data': bad value of `▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒' for attribute `SUPPLIER_NAME'
```

and so on...

If it is related to encoding then how can i convert the entire data set to UTF-8?
Please help me in solving this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Xizam . I have tried to change the encoding of individual columns of the data frame using 

    **c50data$SUPPLIER_NAME<-stri_enc_toutf8(c50data$SUPPLIER_NAME)**  and then again i executed the algorithm. confusion is without a single change of code it is working in windows and failing in linux